# Download images to users local machines via Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to download images to users local machines directly via Firebase functions? How to do it in case that:

1. Images are stored in Firebase storage.
2. Images are stored on other cloud storage providers (I can access them with url).

I don't want to download those images via url links so that I don't reveal the url the image is located on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to download images to users local machines directly via Firebase functions?

No, it's not possible.  The client must reach out to the server in order to download content.  The content can't be "pushed" to the client without its authorization.  That would be a huge security hole for the client.

This is why download URLs exist - to give the client something to download via a normal HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a presigned URL using the Google APIs library. The Firebase bucket is just a regular GCS bucket. Something like this:

```
const admin = getFirebaseAdmin();
let bucket = admin.storage().bucket(firebaseConfig.storageBucket);

const f = bucket.file(location);
if (!(await f.exists())) {
    throw logError(`No file found at specified location: ${location}`, functionName)
}

const url1 = await f.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: new Date((new Date).getTime() + (24 * 60) * 60000)   // expires in 24 hours
});
const url = url1[0];

return url;
```

Comment: The question says: "I don't want to download those images via url links so that I don't reveal the url the image is located on."

Comment: The presigned url creates a temporary URL that you can expire after, say, an hour. In my example it expires in a day.

Comment: Also, you can actually set your Firebase storage rules to prevent all reads, and then allow a file to be read through this mechanism. That avoids creating a "Security through obscurity" issue -because here does not EXIST a public URL once your temporary, presigned URL expires.